# Subversion post-commit from different user

Tags: svn, post-commit

I've installed subversion and have the following setup:

```
Repo: /home/svn/tester (apache:apache) 
The site is: /var/www/tester (tester:tester)
```

I've checked out the tester repo to `/var/www/tester`

What I am trying to do is keep the owners of the files in `/home/svn/tester` = apache and the owner of files in `/var/www/tester` = tester

Now (after commit) owner of the files in `/home/svn/tester` is Apache

My post-commit file:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/svn update /home/svn/tester
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update local working copy instead of repository:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/tester
```

Comment: sorry, i was wrong when i ask question, my post-commit file
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/tester